# Class initialization inside controller

Tags: php, controller, parent-child

I have a model -

```
class Model{
    public $childModel;
     public function getModel($url){
     $this->childModel = 'model/'.$url;
     include($this->childModel);
     new ModelHomeHome();
     }
    }
```

this is child model -

```
class ModelHomeHome extends Model{
    function __construct(){
        echo 'This is Home Model.';
    }

}
```

a Controller Class -

```
class Controller{
public $model;
 function __construct(){
  $this->model = new Model();
 }
}
```

and this is the child controller -

```
class ControllerHomeHome extends Controller{
 function help(){
 $this->model->getModel('home/home.php');
 }
}
```

and in a page -

```
include(controller.php);
include(model.php);
```

The problem is the child model class is not initializing. **Fatal error: Call to a member function getModel() on a non-object ...** .

If I place the `$this->model = new Model();` inside the `help()` function of the child controller instead of placing inside the parent controller, it works. But I want to initialize the model inside the constructor of parent controller. Please help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're creating the objects and calling the help function?

Comment: actually I have made the code too short in this question. My original code is bigger. I have shared the shorten code. 
And I have solved it with R.N.D. .Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the path to your file. Most frameworks I have seen usually have files all over the place so I try to have constants that ensure I am in the correct parent director when retrieving files.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me when I include the model and controller class and run the following code

```
include('controller.php');
include('model.php');

$home = new ControllerHomeHome();
$home->help();
```

outputs:

```
This is Home Model.
```